# SwiftUI: MagnificationGesture does not fire

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to add a MagnificationGesture to a screen, but it does not fire. I tried to add the gesture via `.gesture`, `simultaneousGesture` etc., but not difference. It seems to me that the scroll view's gesture has priority, but I can't find out how to have both gestures simultaneously recognizable.

```
...
@State private var magnification: CGFloat = 1.0

var body: some View {

        let magnificationGesture = MagnificationGesture(minimumScaleDelta: 0)
            .onChanged({ value in

                self.magnification = value
            })
            .onEnded({ value in

                self.magnification = value
            })

        return Group {

            VStack {

                TitleView(title: NSLocalizedString("timeline.title", comment: ""))

                ScaleView(viewModel: viewModel)

                ScrollView(.horizontal) {

...
                }

                Text("\(String(describing: magnification))")
            }
        }
        .gesture(magnificationGesture)
    }
```

EDIT: I created a standalone variant with the same misbehaviour:

```
//
//  TimelineMock.swift
//  Testprojekt
//
//  Created by Gerhard Schneider on 31.07.19.
//  Copyright © 2019 innoreq GmbH. All rights reserved.
//

import SwiftUI


struct TimelineView: View {


    @State private var magnification: CGFloat = 1.0


    var body: some View {

        let magnificationGesture = MagnificationGesture(minimumScaleDelta: 0)
            .onChanged({ value in

                self.magnification = value
            })
            .onEnded({ value in

                self.magnification = value
            })

        return Group {

            VStack {

                Text("Title")
                .foregroundColor(.red)

                ScrollView(.horizontal) {

                    ZStack {

                        ForEach(0 ..< 10) { index in

                            HStack {

                                Text("Cell")
                                    .foregroundColor(.green)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                Text("\(self.magnification.description)")
            }.gesture(magnificationGesture)
        }
    }
}


#if DEBUG
struct TimelineView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {

        TimelineView()
    }
}
#endif
´´´
```

Comment: I removed my answer, because you already corrected my proposed changes in your question (property name, missing .gesture()). Since there are many bits of your code missing, it is hard to reproduce. I would start by moving the .gesture to the VStack, not the Group.

Comment: The scroll view just has a ZStack with a ForEach loop, bound to the view model, which is left out at the beginning, so nothing special.

Comment: I moved the `.gesture` to the VStack, no change. The question seems to be: how can I manipulate the default drag gesture for the scroll view, so that my magnification gesture is checked first?

Answer (score 0):

I updated to Xcode 11 beta 5 and macOS 10.15 beta 5, and it seems to work now.

Comment: ...well, not really: the scroll view must be "pushed" first, so that it scrolls itself, and slows down, and stops, and then the zoom gesture is recognized.

Comment: Yes, I am trying the same with Image and it apparently only works  after I use drag gesture on Image a few times.